# JSBIN vs LESS CSS

Tags: css, less, jsbin

Is it possible to make LESS CSS work with JSBIN?

Under Add library we can add Less 1.1.3, but I'm not sure if or how I can make it work.

Test:

http://jsbin.com/idekiz/1/edit

Comment: Try http://tinkerbin.com/ instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSBin already supports LESS.  In the CSS pane, just click the big **CSS** and a dropdown menu will appear.  LESS is one of the options.

[image]

#### [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/idekiz/3/)

Comment: Thanks! How could I miss that dropdown?